# Printing multiple pages results in negative offset

Tags: ubuntu, printer, cups

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 and a Samsung CLP-510N network printer with DIN A4 paper.

The printer is configured in the printer settings on Linux as page size A4.

When I print something consisting of more than one page, the content of the page will move higher up on the page for every consecutive page. Eventually the top will be cut off and the bottom half of the paper will be more and more empty.

What can i do?

Comment: Contact the printer manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the printer is still set for the slightly shorter "letter" size, 11 inches (28 cm) tall. Try the following

- Check that you have the [latest update of *CUPS*](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-cups) printer driver.
- You may need to [set the paper size *per printer*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012796/how-to-set-papersize-in-ubuntu), as well as globally.
- Finally, a kluge when all else fails: set a *custom* page size [by printing to PDF, and then printing the PDF to paper](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119004). This is not optimal workflow, and will take experimentation to get right height, but should only be needed if the suggestions above fail.

Hopefully, it's just setting the specific printer.

Comment: And, for good measure, make sure the guides in the paper tray are against the paper, so the printer itself knows the paper size, too.